# How to get same key with value in 2 different tuples

Tags: python-3.x

dept_id = [(121, 20000), (121, 30000), (122, 20000), (123, 40000)]

121 - is ID
20000 -  is salary
Now I want to print

Average of each dept from above

Answer (score 0):

One way to do is as follows:

```
dept_id = [(121, 20000), (121, 30000), (122, 20000), (123, 40000)]
dict1={}
for eachtuple in dept_id:
     if(eachtuple[0] in dict1.keys()):
        dict1[eachtuple[0]]=(dict1[eachtuple[0]]+eachtuple[1])/2


    else:
        dict1[eachtuple[0]]=eachtuple[1]

print(dict1)
```

output:

```
{121: 25000.0, 122: 20000, 123: 40000}
```